# How to integrate a facebook app in a facebook group?

Tags: facebook-apps

Is it possible to integrate functionalities from a facebook app into a facebook group? For example a karma system? Are there any APIs for that?

A tutorial would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use application within Facebook group nor alter groups functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; did you mean "nor" alter groups functionality?